# Installing django-recaptcha

Tags: django, captcha, recaptcha, django-recaptcha

I am trying to install django-recaptcha. I typed

```
pip install django-recaptcha==0.0.4
```

I am not able to install it. The error i face is this:

```
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/captcha': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/Projects/drinker/build/django-recaptcha/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/x6/1rbbd59j1w7dx74lrrs181vh0000gn/T/pip-axdzU5-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /Users/Projects/drinker/build/django-recaptcha
```

I added 'captcha' to the settings.py but it gave me this error:

```
Error: No module named captcha
```

Need some help on this....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing as sudo user as it clearly says "permission denied",

sudo pip install django-recaptcha==0.0.4

Comment: try `pip freeze > requirement.txt` and take a look at that file for `django-recaptcha==0.0.4`

Comment: when trying pip install Django==1.4 , it says Requirement already satisfied

Comment: seems its installed, now try adding it to your settings as an app

Comment: typed this in 'captcha' in installed apps... Error: No module named captcha

Comment: i tried everything but still i see following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'captcha'`. i have following `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'captcha', ...]` in the settings.py file. I installed captcha using `install django-recaptcha==0.0.4` also tried `pip install django-simple-captcha` No luck!